# MySQL: Using Case statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables called 'Employees', 'Managers', 'Supervisors'

```
Employees
ID    Name
 1     Bob
 2     Alex
 3     Joe
 4     Melissa
 5     Hannah

Managers
MID   Name  
1     Bob
3     Joe

Supervisor
 SID   Name
 3     Joe
 4     Melissa
```

I am trying to check whether if an employee is either a manager or a supervisor or both, and have a result table that looks like

```
ID   Manager   Supervisor
1    Manager   NULL
2    NULL      NULL
3    Manager   Supervisor
4    NULL      SUPERVISOR
5    NULL      NULL
```

I want to try using a case statement in order to determine whether a fellow Employee ID is either a manager and/or a supervisor. But i'm not sure how to do this.

I know that I have to do something like

```
SELECT e.id /*how do i select the last 2 columns bc they are new?*/
FROM Employees e, Managers m, Supervisor s
CASE WHEN e.id = m.mid THEN 'manager' /*i don't think this is the correct format*/
CASE WHEN e.id = s.sid THEN 'supervisor'
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `left join`.  Follow a simple rule:  do not use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.  Ignore anyone or anything that tells you otherwise.  Such advice is very out-of-date.

```
select e.id,
       (case when m.mid is not null then 'Manager' end) as Manager,
       (case when s.sid is not null then 'Supervisor' end) as Supervisor
from employees e left join
     managers m
     on e.id = m.mid left join
     supervisors s
     on e.id = s.sid;
```

Also note that your tables are not properly normalized.  Because managers and supervisors are employees, you should only have the `name` column in the `employees` table.  It should not be repeated in the other tables, unless the same person could have different names when they take on the different roles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID , (
 SELECT MID AS Manager
 FROM Managers WHERE MID = ID 
 LIMIT 1
) AS Manager, (
 SELECT SID AS Supervisor
 FROM Supervisors WHERE SID = ID
 LIMIT 1
) AS Supervisors
FROM Employees
```

This will display your result as follows

```
ID   Manager   Supervisor
1    1         NULL
2    NULL      NULL
3    3         3
4    NULL      4
5    NULL      NULL
```